# Error when trying to start VM

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

I want to install a Manjaro on VirtualBox. I've been trying for a 6-7 hours now, but when I start any VM I get this message:

> WHvCapabilityCodeHypervisorPresent FALSE! Make sure you have enabled the "Windows Hypervisor Platform". (VERR_NEM_NOT_AVAILABLE).
> VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX).

> Result code:
> E_FAIL (0x80004005)
> Components:
> ConsoleWrap
> Interface:
> IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}

The Windows Hypervisor Platform is turned on, and I also turned on both virtualization options in the BIOS settings (HyperV is turned off of course).

What’s weirdest is that it worked a few weeks before that. I haven't installed any drivers since then, maybe there was a Windows update. I also can't select 64bit operating systems (I could before).

Info that might help: I have legacy boot only. CPU: Intel Xeon W3520, Palit G1030, Windows 10

I reviewed forums without success. Does anyone has any ideas why it could happen?

Comment: Also something same happens with VMware.

Comment: Thank you guys for formatting, not really used to write here!